# What's the name of the "tongue" of a mortise lock?

Tags: doors, lock

A mortise lock has one or two "tongues" that enter into the frame of the door to keep the door closed, one that is pushed by a spring and moved using the handle, and the other is moved by the key. Like for example the mortise lock in this image, featuring two "tongues":

https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Einbausich-u-schl-3.jpg

[image]

I didn't know what other word to use, so I was using "tongue", but I notice that's not a complete alien word for such products, some vendors include the word "tongue", for example this one: [Double Tongue Shift Door Lock Furniture Cabinet Door Drawer Lock](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Double-Tongue-Shift-Door-Lock-Furniture-Cabinet-Door-Drawer-Lock/32937440312.html)

Comment: "latch" and "bolt" are terms I have heard,

Comment: I have also heard the term “throw” or  “latch throw”

Comment: Thanks. It looks like the one moved by the door handle is named "Spring Latch".